# MySQL query with multiple AND's

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, where-clause

I'm new to MySQL and I'm having problem with a query using PHP. See the three last lines.

```
$query = "
SELECT post_content, slug, ID
FROM wp_posts

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id

INNER JOIN wp_terms
ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id

WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key <> 'include' AND meta_key <> 'exkludera'
OR post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key = 'include' AND meta_value = '72'
OR post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key = 'exclude' AND meta_value <> '72'
";
```

With the three last lines I want to say:

Row 1) Select query if it:
Is publish, Has a-slug and doesnt have meta_key "include" or "exclude"

Row 2) Select query if it:
Is publish, Has a-slug, have meta_key "include" and meta_value is '72'

Row 3) Select query if it:
Is publish, Has a-slug, have meta_key "exclude" and meta_value is not '72'

But it gives me back double or tripple of each select.
It should only be selected if it matchhes one of these three senarios. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use brackets:

```
WHERE (post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key <> 'include' AND meta_key <> 'exkludera')
OR (post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key = 'include' AND meta_value = '72')
OR (post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key = 'exclude' AND meta_value <> '72')
```

Just mixing `OR` and `AND` statements like you do in your example evaluates to `true` for all cases where `post_status = 'publish'`.

By the way, I am assuming that `Row 1)` etc. refers to the lines in your code, not the rows you want returned from the database...

Comment: I have tried that, but no difference. Yes with "row 1 row 2 and row 3" I mean the last three rows in my example. Please have a look again.

Comment: Perhaps there is an additional problem in your `join`'s; do you get duplicate rows?

Comment: Yes there are two or three duplicate rows for me. Will try it without joins.

Comment: @Hakan I'm not that familiar with Wordpress so I don't know where all the fields come from, but adding (left...) joins one by one will probably show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It should help to put parentheses around the separate sets of criteria.

e.g.

```
$query = "
...
WHERE 
(post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key <> 'include' AND meta_key <> 'exkludera')
OR 
(post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key = 'include' AND meta_value = '72')
OR 
(post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND meta_key = 'exclude' AND meta_value <> '72')
";
```

In fact, since some of the criteria are common, you could rewrite it like this:

```
$query = "
...
WHERE 
post_status = 'publish' AND slug = 'a-slug' AND
(
 (meta_key <> 'include' AND meta_key <> 'exkludera')
 OR 
 (meta_key = 'include' AND meta_value = '72')
 OR 
 (meta_key = 'exclude' AND meta_value <> '72')
)
";
```

You can also use `DISTINCT` to ensure only one copy of each record is returned, if necessary.

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_content, slug, ID
```

Comment: Didn't slove my problem, but very good to know! Thanks! I have located the problem, the last three row works witout the joins. So it must be something about them...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue.

I believe the problem is that you aren't wrapping your OR when combining them with the ANDs you are using. When using OR and AND together they must be wrapped in parens "()" or you will have a conflict.

Here's a link showing example and well written descriptions of how this works: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp